# How to publish the particular .Net Core project automatically whenever it is built by Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, build, publish

I know it is easy on the command line - just run `dotnet publish` instead of `dotnet build`, but I am building inside Visual Studio and I want a certain .Net Core project to essentially execute the `dotnet publish` logic whenever VS builds it.

I am expecting for some kind of a build property. Tried to google it - did not find...

Comment: I don't think there's an option to automatically publish the project when building, VS has a specific "publish" action to do that. You can add a postbuild command that executes the "dotnet publish" if the build is success.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding the following lines to the project file:

```
  <Target Name="SetNoBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <NoBuild>true</NoBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PublishAfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="SetNoBuild;Publish" />
  <Target Name="CleanAfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterClean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishDir)" Condition="'$(PublishDir)' != ''"/>
  </Target>
```

I wonder if there is a simpler approach.

Comment: This works well. I'm curious to know if you found anything better or simpler ?

Comment: No, I have not. But I was not reviewing it since long ago.

Comment: This code had no effect for me.  Can you tell me how to trigger it to start working?

Comment: I am not in the context any more, sorry.